# array elements gets deleted when looping files

Tags: loops, perl, file-handling

I have a problem with looping through file names, my input array elements gets deleted.

CODE:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
use strict;


my @files = ("file1", "file2", "file3");

print Dumper(\@files);

for (@files) {
        my $filename = $_ . '.txt';
        open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
          or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
        while(<$fh>) {
                print "$filename read line \n";
        }
}
print Dumper(\@files);
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'file1',
          'file2',
          'file3'
        ];
file1.txt read line
file2.txt read line
file3.txt read line
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

FILE CONTENTS:

```
 cat file1.txt
asdfsdfs
 cat file2.txt
iasdfasdsf
 cat file3.txt
sadflkjasdlfj
```

Why does the array contents get deleted?
(I have 2 different workarounds for the problem, but I would like to understand what's the problem with this code.)

Comment: Corrected, + added file contents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while (<$fh>)
```

is short for

```
while ($_ = <$fh>)
```

so you are clobbering `$_` which is aliased to an element of `@files`. You need to protect `$_` as follows:

```
while (local $_ = <$fh>)
```

Better yet, use a different variable name.

```
while (my $line = <$fh>)
```

Comment: I also found that solution here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're using `$_` in two different ways inside of the loop (as the current filename and as the current line) and they're clobbering each other. Don't do this. Name your variables, e.g.:

```
for my $file (@files) {
    ...
    while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can imagine that your current code does this after reading each file:

```
for (@files) {
   undef $_;
}
```

Comment: That was my workaround too. The other is to slurp the file into an array with @lines = <$fh>. Thanks.